# Symfony 5.4 - Public services do not seem to work

Tags: symfony, service, public

Public service seems to be broken

Error:

**Service "BaseService" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "classes\classBundle\Controller\DefaultController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "message_bus", "messenger.default_bus", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.**

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Services/'
    classes\:
        resource: '../bundles/classes'
    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
    BaseService:
        class: App\Services\BaseService
        public: true
```

Below is the Service.  The most simple example possible.  I have to move a bunch of old Symfony code to 5.4 and on initial project they were all public (original was Symfony 3).

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

class BaseService
{

}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace classes\classBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController as Controller;
use App\Service\BaseService;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->get("BaseService");
        return new Response("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should forget to use $this->get('something'). Set default to autowire and autoconfigure then just inject service through method signature for Controllers or constructor for services

Answer (score 0):

The moment you start a Symfony app, your container already contains many services. So, If you need a service in a controller, just type-hint an argument with its class (or interface) name. Symfony will automatically pass you the service you need.

You can read more about this:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-autowiring-to-automate-the-configuration-of-application-services
- https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/service_container.html#fetching-and-using-services